# Displaying value(Stored in local storage) in javascript drop-down box

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am working on a phonegap project, In which I have a dynamic list of countries coming from backend. Ex. USA, Canada, India. I have to display USA as a default selected value which is working fine. Now the problem is - when I select Canada from drop-down box and if I exit(force close from setting) the value gets stored on Local storage/DB but it doesn't display as a selected value in drop-down window. 
I searched for displaying dynamic value stored in DB and display in drop-down.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my Code :

```
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("my_country") == '' || window.localStorage.getItem("my_country")== null )
            {                
                window.localStorage.setItem("my_country",'US');
                window.localStorage.setItem("my_country_name",'USA');
                var ccode = window.localStorage.getItem("my_country");
            }
            else
            {                   
                var ccode = window.localStorage.getItem("my_country");   //previously selected country     
            }


        jQuery.each(result.d.listCountrys, function(key,value)
            {                       
                if(ccode==value.CountryCode)  //to get the previously stored value and that will become selected in drdwn.
                {
                    jQuery("#drpDoctorSearchCountry").append("<option class='ccmp'  value='"+value.CountryCode+"' Selected>" + value.strCountryName+ "</option>");
                    jQuery("#drpBillingCountry").append("<option class='ccmp'  value='"+value.CountryCode+"' Selected>" + value.strCountryName+ "</option>");
                }   
                else
                {   
                    jQuery("#drpDoctorSearchCountry").append("<option class='ccmp' value='"+value.CountryCode+"'>" + value.strCountryName+ "</option>");
                    jQuery("#drpBillingCountry").append("<option class='ccmp'  value='"+value.CountryCode+"'>" + value.strCountryName+ "</option>");                    
                }
            });
```

Comment: Show your code if you want anyone to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

I started writing this answer before the question was edited. Variable names won't match up. But one should get the idea.

---

#### Assumption:

When a user selects (perhaps clicks on) an option (in a select field), it's value is stored in `localStorage`. Say under `localStorage.cPref`.

If the user has (previously) selected such a value, it should appear as the default (first) value in a drop-down.

#### Solution:

Before displaying the options, you should check the user's country preference is already in `localStorage`.

If so, move that country to the beginning of the list (of countries.)

If not so, it'd mean that the user hasn't yet chosen any option, and there no changes need to be made.

Instead of hard-coding the country options in HTML, it'd be best to use a javascript function which accepts a list (array) of countries.

Manipulating this list and then writing the options to HTML would be better than correcting options after they've already been rendered ( if the need be for such correction.)

#### Code:

```
function renderOptions (cList) { // cList is an array of countries.
  var i, selectNode, optionNode;
    if (localStorage.cPref) { // cPref stores the (previously) selected country.
      i = cList.indexOf(localStorage.cPref);
      if (i > -1) {
        cList = [cList[i]].concat(cList.slice(0, i)).concat(cList.slice(i+1));
        // Moving cPref to the front of cList.
      }
    }
  selectNode = document.createElement('select');
  for (i = 0; i < cList.length; i += 1) {
    optionNode = document.createElement('option');
    optionNode.value = cList[i];
    optionNode.innerHTML = cList[i];
    selectNode.appendChild(optionNode);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(selectNode); 
  // you'd perhaps want to use insertBefore(..) instead.
  return;
}
renderOptions(['USA', 'Canada', 'India', 'Mexico'])
// The function call may be hard-coded in HTML or produced by a script (say python.)
```

And that's it! Hurray...

#### Gotcha:

If the client disables javascript he'd not even be able see the select field! Make sure you hard code the select options inside a `<noscript>` tag.

***Hope I helped. :)***

Comment: Where do you see hard-coded country options? He's looping through an array, just like you suggested.

Comment: You are right. Of course he is.

I wrote my answer **before** he submitted the code snippet.

In either case, I suggested not to hard-code. I didn't suggest removal of hard-coding.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am very very new to Java script. I got cList properly with all values. But when I append cList to div "drpDoctorSearchCountry" it doesn't display anything. Please let me know how can I use the "selectNode" to achieve the output i.e. display the last stored value in drop-down. Many thanks again.